# Fix color highlighting on Solarized in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, color-scheme

Right now, the solarized theme will highlight variables in JavaScript if formatted like this:

```
var foo = function (arg1, arg2) {...}
```

but not like this:

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2) {...}
```

Some industry standard style guides (e.g. AirBnB) have no space after the function keyword, so I'd like to modify my color scheme. Is this possible?

Comment: What language are you using - JavaScript?

Comment: Updated the post. I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using a specialized JavaScript syntax, or just the one that comes with Sublime? Is this in a `.js` file, or embedded in `<script>` tags? The more information you can provide, the better. Some screenshots would be nice, too.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm completely unable to replicate this. I've used a number of different color schemes, a number of different Javascript syntax definitions, and the latest builds of both ST2 and ST3, and the presence or absence of a space after `function` has no effect whatsoever on the syntax highlighting...

Comment: No special JS syntax, just the one provided by Sublime. In a `.js` file. I installed the Solarized theme from the website. Here's a [sample screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4181609/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-04%20at%209.46.54%20AM.png). Also, upon looking more closely, it happens for anonymous functions specifically. Really sorry I didn't catch that nuance the first time. Thank you for helping me with this problem, I sincerely appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a single-character fix to a regex in the syntax definition. Select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file browser. Go to the `JavaScript` directory and open `JavaScript.tmLanguage` in Sublime with XML syntax. Scroll down to line 260, which should be this:

```xml
<string>\b(function)\s+([a-zA-Z_$]\w*)?\s*(\()(.*?)(\))</string>
```

Change it to this:

```xml
<string>\b(function)\s*([a-zA-Z_$]\w*)?\s*(\()(.*?)(\))</string>
<!--                  ^ -->
```

where the `\s+` after `(function)` becomes `\s*`. `\s` is any whitespace character, and the `+` after it means `match one or more`. Changing `+` to `*` means `match zero or more`, which is what we want.

Save the file, restart Sublime (just in case), and you should be all set.

---

*Note for Sublime Text 3 users:*

Packages in ST3 are now stored in zipped `.sublime-package` files, so you'll need an extra step. Install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, then open the Command Palette and select **`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`**. Scroll down to `JavaScript`, select it, then scroll down to `JavaScript.tmLanguage` and select it. You can now edit the file as above, and when you save it, it will automatically create a `JavaScript` folder in `Packages`, with the `.tmLanguage` file inside it.

Comment: You. Are. So. Amazing. THANK YOU!!! This quirk has been a splinter in my foot for so long -- annoying, but bearable. I feel such relief. I sincerely appreciate your patience and thoroughness in answering my question.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this.